# What are the optimization networks? Where can I find info?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, theory, neural-network

So, i recently found this term related somehow to neural networks, but I don't find anymore info on this topic, and it seems interesting.

Does anybody know where I can find more info for starters on this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate on in what context you've seen this term? Maybe you can tell us or quote the source where this term appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) algorithms/techniques can be used to optimize solutions to given problems.
Is that what you are looking for?

I recommend you to buy the book [Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325)

You won't regret it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm not sure what you mean by optimization networks, I'm suggesting you Stuart Russel and Peter Norvig's ["Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach"](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), which is sort of a standard book in AI.

I can't find the most recent version(2009) on Amazon though - they are only listing the rather old but not outdated 2nd edition.